# Touchend not allowed to play media element on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, drag-and-drop

According to this article https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/ touchend should be able to trigger a play event on iOS. However in the example below a press on the element fires the action and starts the audio playback. A touch drag fires the action but returns a promise rejection and does not start the audio playback. Any idea on how to work around this?

```
 el.addEventListener("touchend", stb.task.dragEnd );
 el.addEventListener("mousedown", stb.task.dragEnd );
```

Comment: Please update the question with enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm facing right now the same issue. With the click event it does work, but it doesn't fit my needs...